# Using Cake w/ url extensions

Tags: view, routes, var-dump

I am using CakePHP 2.0 (I believe it is v2.0.3.) and PHP 5.3.8.

I am working on an application which utilizes Cake's support for url extensions.  Specifically, I am outputing XML whenever a url request ends in the .xml extension.  If the url request is made without any extension, then my application presents the stardard view.  This all works beautifully --

```
request .../controller/action.xml renders via view/controller/xml/action.ctp while request .../controller/action renders via view/controller/action.ctp.
```

To achieve this, I did the following:

```
1. Added support for url extension; added the following line to route.php -- Router::parseExtensions('xml');
2. Added support request handling; added the following line to MyController.php -- public $components = array('Session', 'RequestHandler');
```

To output xml, I am using Cake's 'XML' class in conjunction with PHP's 'SimpleXMLElement' class.  My problem is that the complete xml is never generated.  The classes are suppose to generate xml based on an input PHP array, however, it appears that the complete array is not processed.  My xml output is partial.

My source code in my view file (.ctp) is as follows:

$simple_xml_elem = Xml::build($xml_array);
echo $simple_xml_elem->asXML();

Interestingly, in the course of trying to debug this problem, I discovered the a similar behaviour can be observed if I simple attempt to dump the view object within the xml view file (../view/controller/xml/action.ctp).  'var_dump($this)' only output a partial dump of the view.  The same view dump performed within the standard view file (../view/controller/action.ctp) outputs a full dump of the view.

It is my believe that Cake is somehow setting up the view environment differently when it routes for a url extension than when the standard view is requested.

Could some please shed some light on the for me before I lose my hair.  Please???? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the response & request objects

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/the-cakerequest-object-in-cakephp-2-0 - the article was written when cake 2 was alpha I think but Mark talks about the concept of request object (another entry for response)

both objects are passed to the controller
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

for now I believe you use the request comp to handle layout switching (although it can be done without it)